# How do I get the same behavior for double precision operations in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, floating-point, double

I have a library that I'm converting to 64-bits. However, I can't get bit-exact results on 64-bit mode, so my tests are failing.

I reduced the problem to a simple test case:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("%d bits: ", sizeof(void*) * 8);
    volatile double d = 10.870191700000001;
    volatile double x = 0.10090000000000002;
    d += x * 30.07;
    printf("%0.15f\n", d);
}
```

To avoid compiler differences, I'm using the same compiler and cross compiling. In this case, I'm using TDM-GCC 64-bit 5.1.0 on Windows 7 in a Core i5 CPU. Here is my command-line:

```
gcc double_test.c -o double_test.exe -m32 -O0 && double_test.exe && gcc double_test.c -o double_test.exe -m64 -O0 && double_test.exe
```

And the output is:

```
32 bits: 13.904254700000001
64 bits: 13.904254700000003
```

In this case the error is minimal, but in my full test cases the error can add up and be enough to double my output.

**How can I get bit-exact operations to match the 32-bit output?**

The nearest I got to something relevant was to use `-ffloat-store`, but in this snippet it got the 32-bit execution like the 64-bit one, while I need just the opposite. However, this didn't have any noticeable effect upon my library. I also tested the `-fexcess-precision=standard` and `-mfp-math` options to no avail.

Comment: Print `x` and `d` with the `%a` format specifier both before and after the calculation.  It will print them as hex floating point and will give you a better idea of where the differences are.

Comment: Try checking to see the differences in your floating-point environment.  There's a lot of information to digest in section 7.6 of the C11 standard.  Of particular interest may be the rounding mechanism which can be gotten with `fegetround()`.

Comment: Can you use SSE2 math in 32-bit mode as well, avoiding the 80-bit x87 temporary registers entirely?  `gcc -m32 -msse2 -mfpmath=sse`.  Oh NVM, if `-ffloat-store` does the opposite of what you want, then you need to use x87 in 64-bit mode, maybe with `-mfpmath=x87`.  This might have big performance downsides, and auto-vectorization can still use SSE2.  You're compiling with `-O3`, right?

Comment: Is your goal to get the _same_ result or the _best_ result?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: The default rounding mode is always NEAREST.  The C11 standard won't help you with this: `gcc -m32` using x87 FP violates it by keeping extra precision for temporaries even across statements, because `-ffloat-store` has extreme performance downsides.  And the OP says they want the extra precision in 64-bit mode as well, rather than strict rounding to 64-bit `double`.

Comment: @Ronan: related: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/ and https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/ for more about x86 FP gotchas.  You might need to use `long double`.  (It's 80-bit x87 FP on Linux, but in the Windows x64 ABI `long double` = `double`, so even `long double` might not help you on Windows.).  (correction to a previous comment: `-m64 -mfpmath=387`, not `=x87`

Comment: It is useful to report `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` of both systems. `printf("FLT_EVAL_METHOD %d\n", FLT_EVAL_METHOD);`

Comment: "but in my full test cases the error can add up and be enough to double my output." --> As the difference in the 2 products is only 1 ULB, that difference is explainable from from different `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  Yet the _real_ solution is to adjust your unposted code to not "double my output".  IOWs, Your approach is too sensitive and needs to be re-thought.  Posting code to demonstrate  "double my output"  would be useful.

Comment: I changed the 64-bit tag to floating-point, since floating-point is more relevant. (64-bit is not even Intel-specific; it is a pretty generic tag which is not as useful here as the floating-point tag.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you said you need the more precise `...01` result, as well as determinism, you unfortunately can't just use `-msse2 -mfpmath=sse` in your 32-bit build.  Future readers looking for determinism should use that.

---

You can use `-mfpmath=387` to ask gcc to use slow/obsolete x87 math in 64-bit mode, where it's not the default.  The calling convention passes/returns FP args in xmm registers, so this is even worse than in 32-bit mode, sometimes requiring extra store/reload.

```
peter@volta:/tmp$ gcc -m64 -mfpmath=387 -O3 fp-prec.c -o fp-64-387
peter@volta:/tmp$ ./fp-64-387 
64 bits: 13.904254700000001
```

I'm not sure if gcc strictly limits itself to x87 when auto-vectorization is possible.  If so, you're missing out on performance.

---

And BTW, in your example the `...01` is the result of keeping *extra* precision in an 80-bit temporary for the `x*30.07` before adding it to `d`.  (`d` is `volatile`, but `d += stuff` is still equivalent to `d = d + stuff` so the `x*30.07` doesn't get rounded to 64-bit `double` first).

**You could use `long double`, e.g. `d += x * (long double)30.07` to force an 80-bit temporary there.**  `long double` is 80 bits in the x86-64 System V ABI Linux/OS X/*BSD/etc, but on x64 Windows it's the same as 64-bit `double`.  So that might not be an option for you.

---

In this case you can get the same result with an FMA which keeps infinite precision for the multiply before doing the add.  This is slow on hardware without FMA support, but `fma(d, 30.07, x)` will reliably give the result you want.

If you need this, use it in the places where that precision is required.

If you compile with FMA enabled, it can inline to an FMA instruction.  (e.g. `-march=native` on my Skylake CPU)

Even without using the `fma()` math.h function, gcc will contract mul+add expressions into FMA when optimizing.  (Unlike Clang, which I think doesn't do `FP_CONTRACT` by default without `-ffast-math`).  Note that I'm *not* using `-march=387`

```
 # your original source code, using an FMA instruction (native=skylake in my case)
peter@volta:/tmp$ gcc -m64 -march=native -O3 fp-prec.c -o fp-64-native
peter@volta:/tmp$ ./fp-64-native 
64 bits: 13.904254700000001
```

The relevant part of `main` is:

```
 57e:   c5 fb 10 44 24 08       vmovsd xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8] # load x
 584:   c5 fb 10 0c 24          vmovsd xmm1,QWORD PTR [rsp]     # load d
 589:   c4 e2 f1 99 05 d6 01 00 00      vfmadd132sd xmm0,xmm1,QWORD PTR [rip+0x1d6]        # the 30.07 constant
 592:   c5 fb 11 04 24          vmovsd QWORD PTR [rsp],xmm0     # store d
 597:   c5 fb 10 04 24          vmovsd xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp]     # reload d
 59c:   e8 8f ff ff ff          call   530 <printf@plt>
```

---

FP determinism is *hard* in general.

See also https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/ and https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/

Comment: @R..: I would recommend that too if they only needed determinism, but the question says they really want the more precise `..01` result, not the `..03` result.

Comment: @R..: but thanks for pointing that out, added a section at the top to recommend that for everyone else.

Comment: I see OP requested the “opposite” result but not that they requested a more precise or more accurate result. My interpretation of their request for the “opposite” result was they were requesting the 32-bit result, not requesting a more accurate result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's true, perhaps there's some other reason for needing to match the 32-bit result.  I upvoted R..'s answer.  But it seems likely they do think they need extra precision, because they're considering things like recompiling the 32-bit version with `-ffloat-store`.  Anyway, I think the multiple answers collectively answer whatever someone might be asking if a search takes them here, or at least get them started.

Comment: Absolutely great answer! Many concepts I still need to grasp are touched. However, what really fixed my problem was actually your comment to my question: since I was still debugging, optimizations were off. When I enabled, even with only `-O1`, my program started giving correct results. Thanks a lot @PeterCordes! Now I have a starting point and can check each optimization to find what is the problem. What still puzzles me is that on 32-bit the optimizations were also off, but I didn't hit this problem.

Comment: @PeterCordes to clarify my requirements, I don't need *absolute, bit-by-bit precision* on my calculations, and probably I traced the test sample to something which may not be correct. However, I'm implementing a standard, which has (printed) tables with some results I need to replicate by some decimal places. Due to those problems I met, some results were doubled or halved, which of course is unacceptable for any number of significant digits. Anyway, as some people write, some results are wrong if you can't replicate it bit-by-bit.

Comment: @RonanPaixão: `-O0` still computes a single statement in registers, not rounding off the `30.07*x` to 64-bit `double` before adding the old value of `d`.  Since it's 32-bit using x87, this is done in 80-bit precision.

Comment: @RonanPaixão: IEEE FP requires that all the basic operators (+ - * / and sqrt) give correct results to within 0.5ulp, i.e. all the signficand bits correct to the nearest representable value.  If a chain of calculations doesn't have enough precision after that, you should be looking at the numerical stability of what you're doing.  e.g. look for catastrophic cancellation when subtracting two nearby number.  Simply increasing precision for temporaries might be a sufficient band-aid for some compilers / options, but numerical techniques for side-stepping / correcting rounding error are possible.

Answer (score 2):

I would not aim to reproduce the 32-bit output, since it's a consequence of excess precision in the 32-bit x86 (x87) ABI and possibly also compiler non-conformance. Instead try to match the 64-bit output which is what you should expect on good targets. As long as you're okay with requiring a machine with sse2+, `-mfpmath=sse` will make 32-bit x86 behave like 64-bit and other more reasonable targets.

If you really need the result from 32-bit x86, ideally you should write it portably. This might involve breaking things down into a pair of `double`s, but for x86-only you could just use `long double`. In the particular example in your question, the `fma` function would work, too.